Handling Replication Lag with ProxySQL in a Spring Boot Application using MySQL InnoDB
I am working on a Spring Boot application using MySQL 8.0.39 with InnoDB and ProxySQL for load balancing between a master and a slave MySQL server. The database is configured to split read and write traffic, with all write operations directed to the master and read operations to the slave.
The challenge I’m facing is that after inserting data into the master, when I immediately attempt to read it, the query is sent to the slave, which occasionally hasn’t yet received the replication update due to lag. This results in a "row not found" scenario for recently inserted data.
I would like to implement a solution where if a read operation on the slave does not find the data (due to replication lag), the application would automatically attempt to fetch the data from the master.
Could someone please suggest the best approach to handle this issue? Specifically, I’m looking for a way to:

Detect when the data is not yet available on the slave.

Redirect the query to the master in such cases.

Ensure this happens only for such cases and doesn’t degrade performance or consistency.


I am using ProxySQL, Spring Boot, and Spring Data JPA.
Any advice or best practices would be highly appreciated.
